# No consigo realizar consultas preparadas mysqli

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

Hace poco me entere de que el antiguo driver de consultas no preparadas es vulnerable a ataques de inyección sql. El problema es que no consigo pasar todas mis consultas anteriores a las nuevas.
Para empezar he probado este ejemplo pero no me devuelve resultado
Aclaro que antes de eso hay un require_once que importa el $conn con los datos.
En este caso si hay resultado (no aparece peor existe en la base de datos) pero me gustaría ejecutar un echo por ejemplo si no hay.

```
$id_ass = "14969774_";
$gen_name = '';
$querydata = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM nodes WHERE id_ass=?"); // "?" este simbolo se utiliza para indicar el parametro a utilizar
$querydata->bind_param("s", $id_user ); //pasamos los parametros a utilizar, "s" por que es string o fecha || "i" en caso de ser entero
$querydata->execute();// ejecutamos
$querydata->bind_result($gen_name);// almacenamos
$querydata->fetch();// obtenemos

echo $gen_name; //mostramos resultado

$querydata->close();//cerramos la sentencia
echo "Fin";
```

El error que me da es `[25-Jun-2019 11:31:37 Europe/Madrid] PHP Warning:  mysqli_stmt::bind_result(): Number of bind variables doesn't match number of fields in prepared statement in /ruta/test.php on line 8.` Entiendo el error pero no le ecncuentro solución ya que a mi parecer solo hago un bind param con un solo valor.

Estoy usando PHP 7.0, Saludos.

Comment: Pasas solo una variable pero recuperas varios campos.

Comment: ¿Que campos? No entiendo muy bien esto de las consultas preparadas jaja.

Comment: `SELECT *` trae todos los campos de la tabla. Sin embargo en el bind_result solo pasas una variable para mapear.

Comment: Ahhh, vale, entonces devberia seleccionar SELECT id_ass ¿?

Comment: $querydata = $conn->prepare("SELECT id_ass FROM nodes WHERE id_ass=?"); asi me da el mismo error :/.

Comment: Necesitas en el `bind_result` pasar el mismo número de variables que columnas recuperas con tu consulta, pues lo que hace es vincular dichas variables a cada columna recuperada.

Comment: Ahh ¿Y como hago un num_rows?

Comment: Porque ahora no da errores pero tampoco suelta datos.

Comment: Y los datos existen al parecer en la base de datos

Comment: revisa este ejemplo, seguro te saca de dudas: https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php

Comment: $querydata->num_rows;

Comment: Vale, ya voy entendiendo, gracias.

Answer (score 0):

No creo que pueda ver el contenido de la variable con un simple echo, prueba con un var_dump(); e intenta modificando el código de esta manera.

$id_a

```
ss = "14969774_";
$gen_name = '';
$querydata = $conn->prepare("SELECT id_ass FROM nodes WHERE id_ass=?"); // "?" este simbolo se utiliza para indicar el parametro a utilizar
$querydata->execute();// ejecutamos
$querydata->bind_result($col1);

while ($querydata->fetch()) {
        printf("%i %s\n", $col1);
    }

$querydata->close();//cerramos la sentencia


echo "Fin";
```

Saludos